# Order records from multiple models by attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, model, merge

Given the three models “message”, “profile” and “comment” i want to merge them into one list, ordered by their common attribute “created_at”. I want to accomplish something like the project overview in Basecamp - see 3) here: http://basecamphq.com/tour#overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

messages = Message.all

profiles = Profile.all

comments = Comment.all

list = [messages, profiles, comments].flatten

sorted_list = list.sort_by { |item| item.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%y') }